# Performing MCDC for a condition (A && B && C) || D

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, mc-dc

I have a situation where I need to write few test cases to get complete coverage of the code.
At a perticular branch I got following situation 
if((A && B && C) || D)

```
if((A && B && C) || D)
{
  //perform task 1'
}
else
{
  //perform task 2;
}
```

But with this I am unable to get test case combination for MCDC..
What could be the way out here...

Answer (score 4):

Your way out could be to use the tool [MCDC](https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/MCDC)  to identify possible test cases.

Doing this manually could be really a lot of work, because of the many possible test pair combinations.

I am sorry that I cannot share all the details of my research. I would recomend to start with reading "An Investigation of Three Forms of the Modified Condition Decision Coverage (MCDC) Criterion", published by the FAA (DOT/FAA/AR-01/18).

Including Masking there are 52 possible test pairs. If you do a proper WhiteBox Analysis, including boolean short cut evaluation, then you will find even 63 MCDC test pairs. Apllying the set cover algorithm will result in 3 possible minimum test sets.

Doing some heuristics will lead to the maybe surprising test vector:

```
 Test Pair for Condition 'a':    0  14   (Unique Cause)
 Test Pair for Condition 'b':    8  14   (Unique Cause)
 Test Pair for Condition 'c':   12  14   (Unique Cause)
 Test Pair for Condition 'd':    0   1   (Unique Cause)
```

Testvector: Recommended Result: 0 1 8 12 14

```
0:   a=0  b=0  c=0  d=0    (0)
1:   a=0  b=0  c=0  d=1    (1)
8:   a=1  b=0  c=0  d=0    (0)
12:  a=1  b=1  c=0  d=0    (0)
14:  a=1  b=1  c=1  d=0    (1)
```

Comment: Hi, @Armin Montigny, can you please add a build file explaining how to set up the MCDC software you linked to inside the repository. I tried downloading the zip file of the repository and there's only a readme file in it, which doesn't contain any info on how to compile and run the application on Windows 10. It just says that we have to use the MCDC command to run it, but that command is not recognised in the command prompt.

Comment: This software has been developed with the free MS Visual Studio 2019 community edition. All necessary files are in. The software is a console program. You create the exe and run it. So, download MSVS and compile it. Then run the exe. If you use other compilers, then put everything in one directory and compile all cpp files. Language is C++17. I created also a version on the Raspberry PI with g++.

Answer (score 2):

With MC/DC you have to find, for each condition (input) `i`, a pair of combinations where only `i` toggles, and the output changes.  For `A` to have a toggling effect on the result of `(A && B && C) || D`, `B` and `C` need to be `true` and `D` needs to be `false`.  Similarly, for `B` to have a toggling effect, `A` and `C` need to be `true`, and `D` needs to be `false`.  With `D` it is a bit different: The output toggles on `D` given that at least one of `A`, `B`, `C` is `false`.  This gives the following combinations (`x` represents the toggling input):

```
A B C D
x 1 1 0 - for A
1 x 1 0 - for B
1 1 x 0 - for C
q r s x - for D, where q + r + s < 3
```

By multiplying out the lines for `A`, `B`, and `C` we get (added lines numbers and column `R` for the result):

```
#  A B C D  R
1  0 1 1 0  0 - for A
2  1 1 1 0  1 - for A
3  1 0 1 0  0 - for B
4  1 1 1 0  1 - for B (duplicate)
5  1 1 0 0  0 - for C
6  1 1 1 0  1 - for C (duplicate)
7  q r s x    - for D, where q + r + s < 3
```

Lines 4 and 6 are duplicates of line 2.  To represent line 7, we can use one of the lines 1,3,5 and add the same line with `D` set to 1, which gives the following result (picked line 1):

```
#  A B C D  R
1  0 1 1 0  0 - for A and D
2  1 1 1 0  1 - for A,B,C
3  1 0 1 0  0 - for B
4  1 1 0 0  0 - for C
5  0 1 1 1  1 - for D
```

That's one possible solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think one way could be for all the false combination of (A && B && C) keep D = 1 and for true combination of (A && B && C) keep D = 0 and at the last Keep all inputs 0. So test case combination can be:

```
a b c d
0 1 1 1
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: The reasoning is almost correct, but you would have to keep D equal to 0 (false) so that changing a/b/c actually has effect — see the other answers which do this indeed.