# How to cleanly unit test a control flow method

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I have a validation method that returns true if a callback should be skipped after save on a record, otherwise it returns false.

The method is complex with multiple return statements if curtain conditions are true. I am lost on how to cleanly test the method and confirm that each test is testing a different condition.

I am using Rails and Minitest, but believe that this is a general question about unit testing that could apply to other languages and/or test frames.

I have tried testing the method and ended up with a mess.

- return true if no fields of interest have changed and not a bulk_association
- return true if bulk association but no associated user
- return true if  bulk association, and associated user, but not active
- return false if bulk association and associated active user
- return false if attribute_a has changed and associated active user
- return false if attribute_b has changed and associated active user
- return false if attribute_c has changed and associated active user

Each test required more setup, and there was no way for me to prove that they where not all returning true on the same line.

```
def skip_callback
  return true unless (self.attribute_a_changed? || self.attribute_b_changed? || self.attribute_c_changed? || self.bulk_association == true)

  user = self.user
  return true if user.blank?
  return true unless user.active
  false
end
```

How should a method like this be tested? I am trying to write good unit tests that are readable, independent, and truthful so if I comment a return out the correct test should fail.

Comment: Note each condition is not mutually exclusive.

Comment: *"The method is complex with multiple return statements"* -- If the method you're trying to test is complex and "messy", then it can be very hard to write "simple" tests for it. A good solution may involve redesigning the original method, before trying to write tests.

Comment: It's hard to give concrete helpful advice without seeing a "full" code sample. Why are conditions A, B and C "complex, and not mutually exclusive"? Can you provide (perhaps a simplified) code sample that fully illustrates the scope of the problem?

Comment: @tom-lord
Thanks for the replies, I have tried to be more specific in my question

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to use a mocking library to ensure the conditions for each case:

https://github.com/freerange/mocha

Your tests would be then be written something like this:

```
your_test_object.expects(:attribute_a_changed?).returns(true)
```

Please not that this approach is not without drawbacks, but it might be worth investigating anyway.

Comment: Thanks I have used mocha before and realize that it makes tests more brittle to change in the code. It would have the benefit that I could test order of the calls and make sure the lower cost checks happen before the higher cost ones. It does not solve the issue that my test are not indendent as the later conditions depend on the earlier conditions and there is no way to know which case returned true in each tests.

Comment: I agree with your experiences regarding the tests becoming tied to the current implementation, but it might still be an option to ensure that some conditions are fulfilled for checking the others?

Another approach would be to start writing a test that makes the method return `false` and then work backwards through the conditions from there?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code example, I see two possible approaches to address your testing problem, which can also be combined.

**First**, you could design your test cases using MC/DC (modified condition / decision coverage).  The idea behind it is the following: For each Boolean input `b` to your code identify two test cases which have the following properties: a) One of the test cases has an expected `true` result and the other has an expected `false` result.  b) Both test cases have the same inputs, except for `b`, which in one test case has the value `true` and in the other it has the value `false`.  In other words, between these two test cases it is only `b` that changes and controls the output.

Example: For the input `self.attribute_a_changed?` to control the output, the other inputs have to have the following values:

- `self.attribute_b_changed?` has to be `false`
- `self.attribute_c_changed?` has to be `false`
- `self.bulk_association` has to be different from `true`
- `self.user.blank?` has to be `false`
- `self.user.active` has to be `true`

Then, one test case with all the above input values combined with `self.attribute_a_changed?` being `true` will result in an expected output of `false` for `skip_callback`.  The second test case will combine the above input values with `self.attribute_a_changed?` being `false` and lead to an expected output of `true` for `skip_callback`.  Having these two tests will give you certainty that you really have checked for `self.attribute_a_changed?` to have an impact on the output.

MC/DC is described in this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_condition/decision_coverage) which also has a link to this [tutorial from NASA](http://shemesh.larc.nasa.gov/fm/papers/Hayhurst-2001-tm210876-MCDC.pdf).  There are also some examples on SO, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37671985/5747415).

**Second**, you could check your test cases by running them against modified versions (mutations) of your code.  This is called mutation testing and is used to judge the quality of the test suite.  To see if one of your test actually finds a special bug (for example, that `self.attribute_a_changed?` does not have the desired impact on the results), simply insert that bug and see if the test fails.  You could, for example, simply delete `self.attribute_a_changed?` from the code and see if your tests notice.  Or, you could invert it into `self.attribute_a_changed? == false` and see if your tests find that bug.

Comment: Thanks, I never heard of MC/DC before but makes sense to get complete test coverage with indendent tests. I will try to take a stab at implementing it today.